# Analyzing packet captures: What is the right approach

Tags: python, machine-learning, scapy, packet-capture

My goal is to build a packet capture analyzer:

**input:** A pcap file (or any capture file). The file could have hundreds/thousands of packets.

**output**: Bunch of information about the traffic streams

```
- How many TCP streams?
- How many UDP streams?
- For a given client (source IP):
     o How many TCP connections were opened
     o How many concurrent TCP connections were opened.
     o What was the longest and shortest session
     o What is the re-transmission ratio for a given stream?
- Given a protocol (say HTTP) identify how many streams had this protocol.
- etc
```

*One obvious way to solve this problem is:*

1. Read the capture & Store the captured data in a data-strucutre of choice.
2. for each of the above queries, write specialized functions to gather the data (i.e parse all streams, capture the stats)
3. Dump the output.

I was planning on using scapy (a python library) for this.

Before I jump into the implementation, I am curious to learn about other possible approaches to the problem:

1. Are there any other frame-works/libraries that make the job easier?
2. Is there a completely different approach that can leverage on AI/ML based frameworks. [I have no prior experience with AI/ML]
3. What is the best way to implement a framework where I can ask a few questions about the data-set and implement functions to respond to the questions?

[ I am very proficient in Python and C, however open to other possible options ]

Update: 10/Nov : I found this: https://github.com/vichargrave/espcap to be a very useful start for what I want to do..

Comment: I am not sure why this was put on hold. What detail is missing in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I recommend you to use Pyshark. this is wrapper for tshark. it also support all of tshark filter, decoder lib, ... and easy to use! This is a great package for parsing .pcap file and also livecapturing*

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshark

```
 import pyshark
cap = pyshark.FileCapture('/root/log.cap')
cap
>>> <FileCapture /root/log.cap>
print cap[0]
Packet (Length: 698)
Layer ETH:
        Destination: BLANKED
        Source: BLANKED
        Type: IP (0x0800)
Layer IP:
        Version: 4
        Header Length: 20 bytes
        Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        Total Length: 684s
        Identification: 0x254f (9551)
        Flags: 0x00
        Fragment offset: 0
        Time to live: 1
        Protocol: UDP (17)
        Header checksum: 0xe148 [correct]
        Source: BLANKED
        Destination: BLANKED
  ...
dir(cap[0])
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_packet_string', 'bssgp', 'captured_length', 'eth', 'frame_info', 'gprs-ns', 'highest_layer', 'interface_captured', 'ip', 'layers', 'length', 'number', 'pretty_print', 'sniff_time', 'sniff_timestamp', 'transport_layer', 'udp']
cap[0].layers
[<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <UDP Layer>, <GPRS-NS Layer>, <BSSGP Layer>]
```

Comment: thanks, I will definitely explore pyshark's capabilities.

Comment: I accepter your answer as it gave me an alternate library to explore. I am still looking for other answers on possible approaches.